# Firefox and Chrome rendering div height differently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

First, thanks for checking out my question. My problem is i'm trying to create a fixed menu at the top of a site, but when i use div elements for the different menu items (to achieve the visual effect i'd like) chrome seems to render the div elements with extra padding at the top, differently than firefox. I've included the code, along with a jsfiddle to show the difference. Any help on how to achieve the desired effect (which is closer to the firefox rendering that the one in chrome as I'm sure you could guess) would be incredibly helpful. I'd like the hover color of the menu items to reach the bottom of the fixed black bar, with the text equidistant top to bottom. Thank you for your time!

EDIT: see below conversation, this is the desired look im going for (rendering correctly in chrome)
http://jsfiddle.net/9wQxu/5/

The code as follows: (apologies for poor formatting)

HTML:

```html
<div id="topbar">
<div class="facebook">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Kristen-Hemphill/359919877367564">
<img src="img/facebook_logo.png" style="width:28px; height:28px; padding-left:5px; padding-top:2px; float:left;" />
</a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/krishemp">
<img src="img/twitter.png" style="width:28px; height:28px; padding-left:5px; padding-top:2px; float:left;" />
</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menuitem'>  <a href="index.php">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menuitem'>  <a href="media.html">LISTEN</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menuitem'>  <a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menuitem'>  <a href="bio.html">BIO</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menuitem'>  <a href="calendar.html">CALENDAR</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menuitem'>  <a href="booking.html">BOOKING</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400);

a:link {color:#000;text-decoration:none; font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}     /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#000;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#36d8e7;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#36d8e7;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}  /* selected link */

.menuitem a{width:auto;
    font-size:30px;
    z-index:9999; 
    float:left; 
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;   
}

.menuitem a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #36d8e7;
    }

#topbar {
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    }

.facebook {
    top:0px; 
    position:relative; 
    float:left;
    }
```

Comment: Are you resetting your css somewhere? You are probably seeing the differences in default browser css. You should always reset with something like this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height: 30px;` to .menuitem in CSS.

**Edit**
I've tried with this CSS:

```css
.menuitem a {
        width:auto;
        font-size:30px;
        line-height:100%;
        z-index:9999; 
        float:left;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;   
}
```

and it should work - but I've got almost 100% same result only when Google font is commented out and Arial is used. So it's obviously a difference in the font-rendering itself. I'm also always going crazy becuase of such differences ;)

Comment: I tried this, but it moves the text down to make the spacing uneven top to bottom. I've updated the entry to reflect my desired effect a bit more clearly.

Comment: with this and bottom padding of 10, i can get the look im going for in chrome. ill edit to update the jsfiddle to show what i mean. it still comes up differently in firefox.

Comment: gahhh finally! it definitely is a font rendering problem! im going to try to link the font from the server instead of using google api and see if that bears any success, and if not, a font change will have to work! thanks so much for your help! i've been struggling for a week with this! id upvote it but i need more rep, which i think is strange.